# Choose best id for each group with least change cost

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, brute-force

I want to assign unique id for each group, but need to restrict the changing cost.

As below, there are 4 groups `(h1, h2, h3, h4)`. There are 3 ids `(id1, id2, id3)`. Change existing id of a group will have cost, for example, change `id1` of `h1` will cost 4.

I want to assign the 3 ids to 3 of the 4 groups, and assign a new id for the other one group. The goal is we need a solution whose **changing cost** is the least.

In the example below, if we finally assign `id3` for `H1`, then the changing cost from `H1` is 7. The total changing cost is the sum of cost of each group.

For the example, the best solution of the example is:

`H1 <- id2, H2 <- New ID, H3 <- id3, H4 <- id1`. Changing cost is 8.

Currently I use a brute-force, which is not efficient especially when number of group/id increases.

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
   id1  id2 id3
H1  4   3   0
H2  1   0   0
H3  2   0   2
H4  3   1   0
```

Comment: what are constraints for number of groups and number of ids?

Comment: number of groups could be less than 100, ids may be around 10.

Comment: Might be worth looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [min-cost max flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) here

Connect source to all ids with capacity 1, connect each id to each h with capacity 1 and cost -a[id[i], h[j]] (as you need to find maximums actually), 
and then connect all hs with sink with capacity 1.

After applying min-cost max flow, you will have flow in those (i, j) where you should assign i-th id to j-th h. New ids for other hs.

Comment: I used the code  [MinCostMaxFlow.java - MIT](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjyk6ey19fHAhWJdh4KHTaRByg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2F~ecprice%2Facm%2Facm08%2FMinCostMaxFlow.java&usg=AFQjCNHctmgDhqtiVLHCT66Lz_6ezW66pg&bvm=bv.101800829,d.dmo) and your suggestion works perfectly.